# How to enable multiple javascript slideshows on one page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking to create multiple slideshows on a single page however it is currently not working

I understand that this question has been asked before but I can't seem to make those answers work with my code, does anyone have any suggestions? I don't have a huge amount of experience with Javascript

```
<div class="bareEditorial">

<div class="slideshow-container" onclick="plusSlides(1)">   

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="bareEditorialHero.jpg">
  </div>
    </div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="image">
    <img src="bareEditorial2.jpg">
  </div>
    </div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="image">
    <img src="bareEditorial3.jpg">
  </div>
    </div>



<div class="ninetydegrees">     
<div class="nextprevious">

  <div class="numbertext">Bare Boutique Editorial 2018 (<span>1</span> / <span>6</span>)</div>
</div>
```

```
var slideIndex = 1;
var indexes = document.querySelectorAll(".numbertext span");
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
indexes[1].innerHTML = slides.length;

showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
var i;
if (n > slides.length) {
slideIndex = 1
}
if (n < 1) {
slideIndex = slides.length
}
indexes[0].innerHTML = slideIndex;
for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
slides[i].style.display = "none";
}
slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
}

$(function() {
  $('body').removeClass('fade-out');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you need information on implementing multiple slideshows on a page and not going into the detailed working for each, I'll suggest you to have a slideshow container with unique id for each slideshow and call your initialization method on each by passing the id as an argument.

Create a method as `initializeSlideshow(containerID)` and in that bind methods to for example next button as

```
function initializeSlideshow(containerID) {
    $('#' + containerID + '.prevLink').on('click', function() {} );
    //rest of your logic
}
```

Another approach would be to add a class to each container and implement the methods in a way that you capture the respective container using `closest()` and manipulate DOM

```
$('.containerClass .prevLink').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('.containerClass').find('.slideCLass');
});
```

In an ideal scenario, one should write code to implement slideshow logic as a plugin where you can simply do

```
$('.slideshowContainer').initializeSlideshow( {
    //slideshow options.
})
```

Which can be implemented as

```
$.fn.initializeSlideshow = function(slideshowOptions) {
    //your logic where reference to this (object on which the method is called) is available
}
```

Comment: Can I ask you a huge favour and demonstrate this on a pen? I'm not fully sure how to implement this 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XQeGMZ

Comment: @glittergirl I can demonstrate how to create a plugin method but not implement slideshow logic